# How to search for a value in an Array of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript and i came across this problem. I want to catch an input value using `document.formName.elementName.value`and compare that value with an instance of an Array object.If the value exists it will throw an alert!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the indexOf() function you simply do this :
`array.indexOf("string")`
It will return -1 if the item is not found, otherwise just the position.
Here's a link [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I think that has been asked thousands of times:

```
if(myFancyArray.indexOf(document.formName.elementName.value) !== -1){
   alert("You did something wrong!");
}
```

Watch out as old versions of IE don’t know `indexOf`. (but who needs IE?)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`indexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)

```
function search(arr,obj) {
    return (arr.indexOf(obj) != -1);
}
```

Test cases:

```
search(["a","b"], "a"); // true
search(["a","b"], "c"); //false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a convenience method to JavaScript's Array

```
Array.prototype.includes = function(element) { 
    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) { 
        if (this[i] == element)  {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

And, then, you can use below code to get some syntactic sugar

```
var myArray = [0,1,"hello","world"];

console.log(myArray.includes("hello")); //prints true
console.log(myArray.includes(10)); //prints false
```